# C# Exception error while running SQL Server query

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm building simple library application. I'm using C# and SQL Server 2017.

While running a function to check if the book already exists I'm getting an error near "Name".

```
        public bool DoesItExist()
        {
            mainSet mset = new mainSet();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM [Library].[dbo].[ViewBook] WHERE " +
                "Title = '" + this.title + "' AND " +
                "DateOfFirstRelease = " + this.release_date + " AND " +
                "Name = '" + this.author_name + "' AND " +
                "2Name= '" + this.author_2name + "' AND " +
                "Surname = '" + this.author_surname + "' AND " +
                "Category = '" + this.category + "' AND " +
                "Publishing = '" + this.Publishing+ "' ";

            SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(mset.dataBaseConect);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);
            cnn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();  

            if (reader.HasRows) return true;
            else return false;
        }
```

All **"this."** are are parameters in "Title" class.

All parameters are type:string except "DateOfRelease" which is type:int

[ViewBook] is a view in [Library] database.

Error I'm getting:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 

An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Name'.”
```

Example of the cmd query:

```
"SELECT * FROM [Library].[dbo].[ViewBook] WHERE Title = 'Book Name' AND DateOfFirstRelease = 2004 AND Name = 'George' AND 2Name= '' AND Surname = 'Martin' AND Category = 'Economy' AND Publishing = 'PublishingTest' "
```

Comment: Don't inject your values, parametrise them! SQL Injection is not your friend.

Comment: I know. it's just a simple school project, so dont want to bother with that ;)

Comment: I really agree with @Larnu! Please use parameters. The way to add them can be seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Well school projects.. I see how this could give you the reasoning not to do it. However if you do something this bad it's **always** wrong. If this becomes a habit you're going to have huge problems. It's best to always do it at least good!

Comment: *"I know. it's just a simple school project,  so dont want to bother with that"* Attitude like that will get your poor grades and, if you continue to use it in the work place, in **a lot** of trouble. Learn how to do things right now, don't be lazy.

Comment: I know all the stuff why it shouldnt be used and how to do it properly. How about an answer to the problem at hand?

Comment: Parametrisation is **part** of the answer.

Comment: OK let's forget sql injection and parameters for now. Then tell me what is the value for the _query_ variable as it appears using a debugger. Look with care how the Date are transformed into the string. Then re-evaluate your decision to not use parameters for this _simple school project_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a *big* caveat with this answer; I'm not a c# coder so I have not tested this. I very rarely go near C#, and only when I do it's because I'm assisting our developers at work with their SQL Server requirements (as I'm a DBA/SQL Developer). What did I do though? I used the documentation ([SqlCommand.Parameters Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8) & [SqlDbType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqldbtype?view=netframework-4.8)) to write a properly parametrised query which *should* work (I added a comment as to why I *believe* your query failed as well):

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM Library.dbo.ViewBook" + 
                " WHERE Title = @Title" + 
                " AND DateOfFirstRelease = @ReleaseDate" + 
                " AND [Name] = @AuthorName" + //Name is a keyword, so I prefer to quote it
                " AND [2Name] = @AuthorName2" + //Quoted as a column that begins with a number needs to be delimit identified
                " AND Surname = @Surname" + 
                " AND Category = @Category" + 
                " AND Publishing = @Publishing;";

    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(mset.dataBaseConect))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Title",SqlDbType,VarChar,50); //Guessed datatype
        cmd.Parameters["@Title"].Value = this.title;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReleaseDate",SqlDbType.Date); //Guessed datatype
        cmd.Parameters["@ReleaseDate"].Value = this.release_date;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@AuthorName",SqlDbType.VarChar,50); //Guessed datatype
        cmd.Parameters["@AuthorName"].Value = this.author_name;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@AuthorName2",SqlDbType.VarChar,50); //Guessed datatype
        cmd.Parameters["@AuthorName2"].Value = this.author_2name;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Surname",SqlDbType.VarChar,50); //Guessed datatype
        cmd.Parameters["@Surname"].Value = this.author_surname;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Category",SqlDbType.VarChar,50); //Guessed datatype
        cmd.Parameters["@Category"].Value = this.category;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Publishing",SqlDbType.VarChar,50); //Guessed datatype
        cmd.Parameters["@Publishing"].Value = this.Publishing;

        cnn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();  
    }
```

Comment: Had just noticed that @Steve . I'm far more used to using T-SQL to build dynamic statements and using `NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10)` :)

Comment: Forgot about the [ ] on Name. All works after adding them. Thanks

Comment: But did you parametrise your query, @DonSlipo?

Comment: @DonSlipo then you have completely ignored the whole point of my answer... Stop making these mistakes now, and fix the **real** problem.